# document.getElementsByClassName("...")[0] returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple list and want to select the first element.

```
<ul>
  <li class="first">Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

My js:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0];
console.log(list);
```

But the console is saying undefined, why is that? How should this be done the proper way?

Comment: did you added this script after the body or inside document.onload?

Comment: Working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/78z1nmqj/)

Comment: Yes i added to the end of the body and it fixed

Comment: Please add more explanation and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Code is going to execute before the HTML code, so when the javascript interpreter executes a line 
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0];
there was no list element is defined, because body element is not yet executed.

So to get it worked, put a javascript code inside a function and call that function using the "onload" event on body tag. By doing this, the function will get called after loading of complete `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was that script tag was entered before the body tag, after i moved to end of body it was fixed